# Http request every X seconds using TimerTask

Tags: java, android, timer, httprequest, timertask

I wanna send request to a server every X seconds, and get results.
Without using timer it works ok, but if i use timer.scheduleAtFixedRate i get exception:

"Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

How can I get rid of this? 
Thanks!

```
public class MainMap extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener , View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int initialDelay = 1000;
        int period = 5000; 
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                //request every 5 seconds
                setPosition();
            }
        };
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period);
    }

    public void setPosition() {
        getCurrentLocation();

        ArrayList<JSONObject> dataDelete = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String,String> mUserDelete = new HashMap<>();

        if (isOnline) {
            mUserDelete.put("available", String.valueOf(1));
        } else {
            mUserDelete.put("available", String.valueOf(0));
        }

        mUserDelete.put("id",user.getId());
        mUserDelete.put("longitude", String.valueOf(longitude));
        mUserDelete.put("latitude", String.valueOf(latitude));
        dataDelete.add(new JSONObject(mUserDelete));
        JSONArray jsonArrayDelete = new JSONArray();
        jsonArrayDelete.put(dataDelete);
        final JSONObject jsonObjectDelete = new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonObjectDelete.put("request", jsonArrayDelete);

            new AsyncServerRequest().execute(jsonObjectDelete);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(Constants.tag, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void getCurrentLocation() {
        lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);

        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

    }


    public class AsyncServerRequest extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Integer, Long> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
            super.onPostExecute(aLong);
        }

        @Override
        protected Long doInBackground(final JSONObject... jsonObjects) {
            final HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest(uriStatus, jsonObjects[0]);
            request.makeHttpRequest();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is this line of code

```
new AsyncServerRequest().execute(jsonObjectDelete);
```

you can't and shouldn't start an `AsyncTask` from a background thread, but always from the the UI Thread. And you probably don't need an `AsyncTask` since the `TimerTask` runs already on background thread